# How to define my group_id with the gradle-mvn-push helper?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I try use the [gradle-mvn-push helper](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push) to publish artifacts to a local Nexus repository.

I started configuring all values in a gradle.properties file.

If I run `./gradlew uploadArchives` I get the following response:

```
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > For artifact {:library:unspecified:aar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
```

The original uploadArchives task has pom.groupId but I don't see a way to defines this in the gradle.properties file for the helper.

My gradle.properties look like this:

VERSION_NAME=2.1
VERSION_CODE=50
GROUP=xxx.xxx.xxx
GROUP_ID=xxx.xxx.xxx

POM_DESCRIPTION= Library
POM_URL=https://xxx.xxx
POM_SCM_URL=xxx.xxx.net:xxx
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@projects.xxx.xx:xx.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:scm:git@projects.xxx.xx:xx.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=...
POM_LICENCE_URL=...
POM_LICENCE_DIST=...
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=jlei
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Janusz Leidgens
POM_NAME=xxxxxx
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=library
POM_PACKAGING=aar
RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL=http://xxx.local:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the group ID you'd need to set a value for the project property [group](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3agroup) in your `build.gradle` file. Here's an example:

```
group = 'org.company'
```

You might also want to try out the [Nexus plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin).

Comment: Seems to work. Strange that the helper has no way to define this through an entry in the property file.

Comment: I'd ask the plugin author about it.